# From the POV of TensorFlow2.0, what is exactly a layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am written to you because I am not sure about my comprehension of what is exactly a layer from the point of view of TensorFlow 2.0.

All my knowledge comes from this page : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules

Can you confirm my definition deducted from this page of what is a layer from POV TF2 :
"Layer is a function with a known mathematical structure that can be reused and has trainable variables. A layer is a personalization of a foundational class called “module”. Layer/module are in fact from Point of View of python are “object” which have states and methods to manipulate theses states."

Do you agree with my definition?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `layer` is a callable object that takes as `input` one or more tensors and that `outputs` one or more tensors. It involves *computation*, defined in the `call()` method, and a *state* (weight variables), defined either in the constructor `__init__()` or in the `build()` method. Users will just instantiate a layer and then treat it as a callable.

For more information you can refer [tf.keras.layers.Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) and it's [methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#methods).